# How can I publish C# WEB project?

Tags: c#

How can I publish C# WEB project?

Comment: You should elaborate a little...

Comment: I'd click *Publish web site* in the *Build* menu. Then follow the instructions (i.e.: select an FTP or IIS location). IIS works only if the Frontpage extensions are installed, otherwise choose FTP or local.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard [VisualStudio publishing for web sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [for WebApplications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453%28VS.80%29.aspx). Just right click on you project and select "Publish..."

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps:

-Right click on your project 
-Click Publish

At this point I prefer to publish to a file location, then copy the files to the relevant application folder on the server. This way I can keep track of releases before they are transfered to production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project --> Publish

Then follow the instruction on there then you be able to generate the files that you can put your hosting